# Implement AVL tree preorder traversal with only self argument

Tags: python, avl-tree, preorder

For this assignment I'm not allowed to edit the method or the calling of it in the driver code, and it only takes a self argument. I'm having a bit of a brain lapse as I can't figure a way to run the method recursively for the left and right nodes.

**Node setup class below**

```
# This is the Node class init within AVl Tree Class.
      

        def __init__(self, val):
            # There are 4 attributes in each tree Node:
            # 1. A piece of data: self.val. (You may consider self.val is an integer here.)
            # 2. A pointer to its left child, which initially points to None.
            # 3. A pointer to its right child, which initially points to None.
            # 4. The height of this node: self.height.
            

            ####################    DO NOT CHANGE THIS   ####################
            self.val = val
            self.left = None
            self.right = None
            self.height = 0
```

**Avl tree init below**

```
def __init__(self, root = None):
        # In most of the designs, a tree is just a pointer to its root.
        # We use the same design here.

        ####################    DO NOT CHANGE THIS   ####################
        self.root = root
```

**obviously incorrect traversal method below**

```
 def preorder_tree_walk(self) -> []:
            print(self.root.val)
        if self.root.left:
            print(self.preorder_tree_walk(self.root.left)) #doesnt work, only self argument#
            if self.root.right:
                print(self.preorder_tree_walk(self.root.right)) #doesnt work, only self argument#
```

This seems to be relatively simple but I am coming up empty brained.

Comment: Where is `self.root` coming from? You need to post a [MCVE] for us to be able to help. I suspect you really just want something like `if self.left: self.left.preorder_tree_walk()` and a matching call for `self.right`, but the code provided is incomplete and incompatible.

Comment: fixed, i accidentally left out the init method for the Avl tree class. The node init at the top is a class within Avl tree , if not clear from the edit.

Comment: I was able to solve it, your comment really helped my thought process, and my teacher for whatever reason made this a very indirect way of solving this one. @ShadowRanger

Answer (score 0):

**Solution: created a list and a method within **

```
def preorder_tree_walk(self) -> []:

    list1 = []

    def rec_preorder_tree_walk(x):
        if x is not None:
            list1.append(x)
            rec_preorder_tree_walk(x.left)
            rec_preorder_tree_walk(x.right)

    rec_preorder_tree_walk(self.root)
    return list1
```